# More efficient way to write command prompts in VBA?

Tags: vba, cmd, ms-word

My macro for Word highlights specific words from a specified list for each document in a folder. At the end of the macro, I would like to append the names of each of these files to include "_Highlight" using the command line. I am not too familiar with using the Command Prompt in VBA, so my code ended up being messy.

I am trying to replicate the following command prompt in VBA.

```
for %a in (“C:\path\*.docx*”) do ren “%~a” “%~Na_Highlight%~Xa”
```

For the actual file path, I select a folder in FileDialog and store it in a variable to be used in the command prompt, `strShellFldr`. I am having some trouble concatenating all pieces of the code, especially with special characters, spaces, and quotation literals.

Here is what I tried:

The code below runs just fine, however it seems quite cumbersome. Is there a more efficient way to write this?

```
Shell.Run "cmd.exe /c" & "for %a in" & Chr(32) & "(" & Chr(34) & strShellFldr & Chr(34) & ")" & Chr(32) & "do ren" & Chr(32) & Chr(34) & "%~a" & Chr(34) & Chr(32) & Chr(34) & "%~Na_Hilight%~Xa" & Chr(34)
```

Is there a native VBA function that allows you to append a file name maybe?

Thank you for your help and my apologies for posting some wretched code on here.

Comment: IMO you should use Scripting.FileSystemObject as someone else has posted, but if your Shell command works I think you should be able to write it as follows:: Shell.Run "cmd.exe /c for %a in (""" & strShellFldr & """) do ren ""%~a"" ""%~Na_Hilight%~Xa""" . In other word, you leave the spaces, you double up double quote characters instead of using chr(34).

Answer (score 0):

This piece of VBA code can loop through a list of files in a given folder as input, and add "_Highlight" at the end of the name, just before the file extension:

example:

`MyFile.txt --> MyFile_Hightlight.txt`

```
Public Sub RenameFiles(Folder As String)
                              
    Dim oFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim oFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim oFile As Scripting.File
    Dim ext As String
    Dim Name As String
    
    On Error GoTo ERROR_TRAP
    
    Set oFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(Folder)
    
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        ext = Split(oFile.Name, ".")(UBound(Split(oFile.Name, ".")))
        Name = Left$(oFile.Path, Len(oFile.Path) - Len(ext) - 1)
        oFSO.MoveFile Name & "." & ext, Name & "_Highlight" & "." & ext
    Next oFile
    
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    
ERROR_TRAP:
    Debug.Print "ERROR : RenameFiles (" & oFolder.Name & ")"
End Sub
```

Do not forget to add `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` reference first in your VB Editor.